# Preheader text box not displayed in the Content tab of the email

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, bug

I am having a really weird issue in Email Studio.

When I open an email, on the first screen I can see the subject and the preheader like in the image below.

[image]

But, when I click in Edit Content, I don't see the preheader text box anymore. Do you know why is this happening?

[image]

Comment: I am noticing that too. If you look at the html of the page, for some reason that element is getting pushed to 'display:none' and the input is not being rendered. This seems like a SFMC issue and not something on the user end. I would put in a support case to get this handled. Also, I checked and it appears to render correctly in FireFox, it seems to only be doing this in Chrome.

Comment: I do agree with @Gortonington ... even I faced the same... and I was able to get that PH section after a `browser cache clear` ... I use Chrome, as suggested by Salesforce support rep!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right, the issue was related to a bug in the MC instance. The preheader box is now displayed well.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you encounter an issue like this, it would be best to try replicating the issue on your Incognito Browser and if the issue is resolved, then go ahead clear your cache and cookies.